# Is there a general formula for $\left [ \mathbb{Q}(a,b):\mathbb{Q}(a) \right ]$?

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

I am trying to solve this problem which states as follows:

> Find the minimum polynomial for $\sqrt[3]{4}+\sqrt{-27}$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$.

Here's what I have done so far (please correct me if I am wrong):

Since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{4})=\mathbb{Q}((\sqrt[3]{4})^{2})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$, and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-27})=\mathbb{Q}(3\sqrt{-3})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$, we have $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{4}+\sqrt{-27})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt{-3})$. And from the question, we would only need to calculate $\left [ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt{-3}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) \right ]$ and $\left [ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt{-3}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3}) \right ]$. Just wondering if there is a general way of solving degree of the form $\left [ \mathbb{Q}(a,b):\mathbb{Q}(a) \right ]$ which might make this easier?

Comment: Yes, there is a general formula, namely the degree of the minimal polynomial. What polynomial did you find?

Comment: What kind of formula are you looking for, that is, what form would your formula take?

Comment: Why did you tag this with [tag:finite-fields]? I think there are infinitely many rational numbers, so nothing of that sort is in sight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Galois Theory. In our case, note that adjoining $\sqrt{-3}$ to $\Bbb Q$ is same as adjoining a primitive third root of unity, let this be $u=(-1+\sqrt{-3})/2$. So we indeed obtain a Galois extension of $\Bbb Q$ after adjoining $a=\sqrt[3]2$ and $b=\sqrt{-3}$. The fields in between are:

- degree $6$: $K=\Bbb Q(a,b)$,
- degree $3$: $L_0=\Bbb Q(a)$, $L_1=\Bbb Q(au)$, $L_2=\Bbb Q(au^2)$, all subfields of $K$, Galois index is $2=6:3$, for short  $L_k=\Bbb Q(au^k)$, with $k=0,1,2$, and below we use tacitly $k$ having one of these values for this reason,
- degree $2$: $M=\Bbb Q(b)=\Bbb Q(-b)$
- degree $1$: $\Bbb Q$.

(Degrees are over $\Bbb Q$.)

Then we can experiment in [sage](https://www.sagemath.org), of course doing such computations with bare hands is not in conformity with the century... (i.e. using internet, stackexchange, but comuting with pencil and paper):

```
sage: R.<x> = QQ[]
sage: K.<a,b> = NumberField( [x^3-2, x^2+3])
sage: a^3 == 2, b^2 == -3
(True, True)
sage: a.absolute_minpoly(), b.absolute_minpoly()
(x^3 - 2, x^2 + 3)
sage: u = (-1+b)/2    # primitive 3.rd root of unity
sage: u^3
1
sage: [ (a*u^k).absolute_minpoly() for k in [0,1,2] ]
[x^3 - 2, x^3 - 2, x^3 - 2]
sage: (a^2+b^3).absolute_minpoly()
x^6 + 81*x^4 - 8*x^3 + 2187*x^2 + 648*x + 19699

sage: S.<Y> = K[]
sage: S
Univariate Polynomial Ring in Y over Number Field in a with defining polynomial x^3 - 2 over its base field
sage: prod( [ Y-(a*u^k)^2-(b*sgn)^3 for k in [0,1,2] for sgn in [-1,1] ] )
Y^6 + 81*Y^4 - 8*Y^3 + 2187*Y^2 + 648*Y + 19699

sage: prod( [ Y-(a*u^k)^2-b^3 for k in [0,1,2] ] )
Y^3 + 9*b*Y^2 - 81*Y - 81*b - 4

sage: prod( [ Y-a^2-(b*sgn)^3 for sgn in [-1,1] ] )
Y^2 - 2*a^2*Y + 2*a + 27
```

For short, the code considered the polynomial ring $S=K[Y]$, and computed first the polynomial obtained by building the product of $Y-c$, for all conjugates $c$ of $a^2+b^3$, which are of the shape $c=c_{k,\pm}:=(au^k)^2+(\pm b)^3$.

If we work over $M=\Bbb Q(b)$, then it is enough to take the  product of $Y-c$ for $c$ of the shape $(au^k)^2+b^3$.

If we work over $M=\Bbb Q(a)$, then it is enough to take the  product of $Y-c$ for $c$ of the shape $a^2+(\pm b)^3$.